# Davinci Resolve hangs at "Loading Fairlight page"

Tags: windows, freeze, video-editing

DaVinci Resolve 16.2 won't start. It hangs at the splash screen showing "Loading Firlight page", although I haven't even installed any of the Fairlight options during Setup.

I already have watched a video, which told me to uninstall, disable the Windows Firewall and reinstall. Unfortunately, that didn't help.

Given the hint that this issue could be related to network activity, I have monitored Davinci Resolve with [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and I see connection attempts to port 1144 and 20312 on my local PC.

I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering about the low port number 1144 (although still above 1024).

Doing a

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicportrange protocol=tcp startport=49152 numberofports=16384
```

fixed the issue.

I chose 49152, because it was mentioned in a [Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929851/the-default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcp-ip-has-changed-in-windows-vista)

> Microsoft customers who deploy servers that are running Windows Server 2008 may have problems that affect RPC communication between servers if firewalls are used on the internal network. In these situations, we recommend that you reconfigure the firewalls to allow traffic between servers in the dynamic port range of 49152 through 65535.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Why did you pick port 49152 as the starting port, though?

Comment: @wecsam: I linked to a Microsoft article. Maybe I didn't fully understand it, though

Comment: Well, I sure don't fully understand it, but that'll do. Thanks for the clarification.